# QTCreator's integrated form editor won't load custom widget plugins (Designer does)

Tags: qt, designer, qt-creator

Trying to use the form editor that is integrated into QTCreator, but even when I place my plugin into QtCreator.app/Contents/MacOS/designer it doesn't show up. The same dylib file does work with the standalone designer app, though.

QTCreator version info:
QTCreator 1.1.0 (Based on QT Version 4.5.1)
Designer version info:
Version 4.5.1

Any hints? This webpage: http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Tools/QtCreator/FAQ, suggested that I have a versioning problem, but that seems nutty as I'm using "pure" 4.5 (clean install and all that)...

Comment: I basically gave up getting creator to load the custom widget dynamically and used promotion instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you made the linker references for the plugin correct? Try

```
otool -L /path/to/plugin/dylib
```

on the plugin binary and see if it's able to reference the Qt libs correctly assuming @executable_path is the designer binary

Answer (score 0):

In QT 4.7, QT Designer plugins should be copied to /qt-install-dir/plugins/designer. Please note, plugins should be created as release not debug!